# Can't run the testing framework in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am learning CasperJS and how to write unit tests but my test fails. I tried the example code from the website and it fails as well! I am confused about how to use the testing framework in CasperJS.

This is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.test.begin('The title exists', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start('http://stackoverflow.com', function() {
        test.assertExists('title');
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

and execute it:

```
casperjs test script.js
```

Output:

```
Test file: test.js                                                              
Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment.
Docs: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#test-command-args-and-options
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: Is this the complete script? If yes, then the error doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ArtjomB. i modify the question , this is my whole code ,i want to check the title is exists or not , but it fails again.

Comment: Remove the first line. It's exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

I override the preconfigured `casper` instance. If I delete the first line, it works without a problem.

Remove:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue, too. Unfortunately, the docs don't spell out very well the different combinations that will both work and that will fail.

If you comment out/remove the first line 
(`var casper = require('casper').create();`) and run your command `casperjs test test.js`, then your script will work.

OR

If you leave in the first line, but don't include "test" as part of your command line: `casperjs test.js` then your script will work.

Notably, the second option produces no output in the console.

If you have both options - telling casper via the command line that you are using the `test` function, *and* trying to create a new instance in the script (when that first line is included) - that is why it gives the error it does. Basically, one or the other will create a new casper instance. You don't need to create it twice.