# How to override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

i have installed the phantomjs 1.9.7 & casperjs 1.1.0 and now i see that all my scripts need to be updated and to remove the first line since it makes the below fatal error:

Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment.
Docs: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#test-command-args-and-options

Reading also in another question i understand that i have to remove now this line from my scripts:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
```

Which is a lot of work since i have meanwhile more then 200 script that needs to be updated!!!

So my question is how can i overcome this issue without updating all the scripts (mentioned in [Can't run the testing framework in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352996/cant-run-the-testing-framework-in-casperjs))

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

if (casper.cli.has("ip") === false) {
  casper.echo("Usage: casper.js test get_info.js --ip=<x.x.x.x>").exit();
}

casper.test.begin('get info', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start("http://" + casper.cli.get("ip") + ":xxxx/man/", function() {
        test.assertTitle("TEST GUI", "GUI has the correct title");
        test.assertExists('form[name="loginForm"]', "login form is found");
        this.fill('form[name="loginForm"]', {
                            'userId': 'xxxxx',
                            'password': 'yyyyy'
        }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Welcome", "Login into TEST GUI");
        this.click('a#test_menu.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        casper.wait(5000, function() {
            this.echo('should appear after 5s');
        });
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("TEST Data", "Login into Data");
        this.click('a#test_menu_data.menu2itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        casper.wait(5000, function() {
            this.echo('should appear after 5s');
        });
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Logout", "Loggin out from TEST GUI");
        this.click('a.minorLinkshighlight');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
        this.exit();
    });
});
```

The above script was working before i installed the phantomjs 1.9.7 & casperjs 1.1.0, the only thing that i can't recall is which version i had before my server had to be reinstalled!

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Test files should never have or have never needed `require('casper').create();` so I am not 100% sure how you have managed to run test scripts in the past. Can you show us a sample script please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is my way of avoiding updating old casperjs scripts due to the overriding of the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment!

go to the casperjs path and edit in path modules:

/../casperjs/modules/casper.js

and remark out the below lines:

```
exports.create = function create(options) {
    "use strict";
    // This is a bit of a hack to check if one is trying to override the preconfigured
    // casper instance from within a test environment.
//    if (phantom.casperTest && window.casper) {
//        console.error("Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment.");
//        console.error("Docs: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#test-command-args-and-options");
//        phantom.exit(1);
//    }
    return new Casper(options);
};
```

This worked for me. You should use it only on your own risk!